# Citation on first line causes whitespace indent

Tags: citing, cite-package, white-space

tex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section*{First Chapter}
\cite{naiveset} First line. \newline
\cite{knuthwebsite} Second line.
\bibliography{test}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\end{document}
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
[1] First line.
[2] Second line.
```

But the result is that the first line is indented with one space, like this:

```
 [1] First line.
[2] Second line.
```

What is the reason, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`cite` package manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/cite):

> **Space before** Regular-text citations have the preceding space adjusted to be a normal inter-word space, even if there is no space in the input. The `[noadjust]` option disables this.  Superscript citations have all precedingspace removed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section*{First Chapter}
\cite{naiveset} First line. \newline
\cite{knuthwebsite} Second line.
\bibliography{test}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\end{document}
```